# Can normally grouped android manifest elements be split into separate elements

Tags: android, android-manifest

Will this (the way I'd like to do it):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
```

have the same effect as this (the way I've seen documented):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" />
```

No errors during compilation and all elements remain in the compiled apk -- but I'm not sure if all the properties are taking effect.

**Edit:** So I guess part of my question is, how do I test the uses-sdk and supports-screens properties?

Why? I'm generating / modifying my AndroidManifest.xml from a script, and the first format is easier to render than the second.

Comment: Well you could always experiment easily with something like `uses-permission` and see if your app can actually get access to everything, regardless of formatting.

Comment: I've tested `uses-permission` and it does work as expected when split up (permissions shown on install). I considered that it however may be an exception as its main attribute is always `android:name`, whereas the above properties support a variety of combinations of attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could have tried it and see if you get any errors or if everything works. Then I think the question would be, "Is there any known issues with doing it this way". I'm not sure about anything in the docs officially stating that you can but they do it if you look

[Here permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

and here

[Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

They are elements belonging to the same tag so they can be grouped together.

Comment: Thanks. I did try it both ways and there were no errors, however that doesn't actually confirm that the property is 'working' for me. I guess part of my question is actually, how can I test that all properties I've used above are actually taking effect?

Comment: Also note that the 'grouped' format is the documented one which I know is supported -- the separated format is the one I wasn't sure about. Clarified above.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can tell you the other way works because I do it that way sometimes and haven't had any problems. Sorry, I don't have anything official except for a functioning app. AFAIK, the only way to test is to set them up that way and see that they do work on the devices/screens as expected and test the permissions to see that you do get WiFi access, etc...

Comment: @wildabeast OK, the only way to test if it works for **your particular requirements** (e.g. the SDK version) is to try it on devices with OK and out-of-date SDK. Otherwise you can't **really** be sure.